# Wubihua / Traditional Chinese / Open-source index

Tags: cjk

I have been looking for an open-source index of Chinese characters (Traditional) indexed for the Wubihua (五筆劃) input method. I have found only partial lists (up to four digits), and only for Simplified. I know there are lists out there, since all the phones in Hong Kong have Wubihua for Traditional installed... Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google (in this case Google T-9) at the rescue:

```
https://code.google.com/p/ibus-t9/issues/detail?id=3
```

[This page has the link to the `table.txt` file].

Not perfect because it lists both Traditional and Simplified characters, but very complete.

**UPDATE**

Link is dead. See the [Github project](https://github.com/microcai/ibus-t9).